# How to navigate to another view controller in the same tab of the tab bar controller in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, navigation, viewcontroller, tabbar

I have a tabbar in my app and in one of the tabs I want to navigate to another view controller - I know how to navigate But the problem is when I used that I can't see the tab bar in the bottom that means I can't go to the other tabs when I navigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to answer without a visual but it sounds like your hierarchy is off. Make sure any content like background images aren't above the nav bar in your view or else it will block the nav bar when you run the app.

Comment: I did it But when I select the that tab has navigation it will be going to the first page in the navigation ( The app doesn't recognized that I am in the same tab )